# Question related to Boolean Algebra.

Tags: lattice-orders

I am asked to prove that order of a Boolean Algebra cannot be prime greater than 2. 
I have a dificulty to show this in an appriopriate way.  I know the definition of Boolean Algebra.
The definition I have seen is as follows: 
A structure (B,meet,join) is called a Boolean Algebra if
B is distributive, a join 1 = 1, a meet 0 = 0 , a join a' = 1, a meet a' = 0.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

*Hint*

See [Boolean algebra (structure)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_(structure)) :

> It can be shown that every *finite Boolean* algebra is isomorphic to the Boolean algebra of all [subsets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)#/media/File:Hasse_diagram_of_powerset_of_3.svg) of a finite set. Therefore, the number of elements of every finite Boolean algebra is a power of two.

See also [Stone representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_sets#Stone_representation).